# How can I record the application output audio as input using Unity Microphone

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, io

Hi I'm making a game about recording in-game audio, but all I can do is recording with internal microphone, the default input audio device. I try to see the list of devices in Unity with `Microphone.devices`, but depend of my Windows configurated devices, I need a solution to work in any computer. Maybe something related to FMOD custom DSP, faking a audio card or some solution in Unity API, I need a north. How I'm using the code:

```
myAudioClip = Microphone.Start ( null, false, 10, 44100 );
```

To save a audio file I'm using that script: https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063

And that line:

`SavWav.Save("myfile", myAudioClip);`

My question is: How to record my application output audio as a input data too in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in Unity. The furthest you can go is record individual AudioClips.

To record system output use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). It's a .NET library, hope it will work on Mono.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I will test it.

Comment: @BrunoAraujo did you test it?

Comment: Not yet @JohnTube , I freeze this game development, sorry.

Comment: @JohnTube I've given up on Unity for some time now. I'm pretty sure my 2016 answer is simply wrong because I just came across this article from 2016, linked below, that will probably help you. If it does, please make another answer to this SO question. https://evanxmerz.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/07/recording-in-game-audio-in-unity/ and in case the link goes dead in the future hopefully this archive will last longer: https://web.archive.org/web/20190409173052/https://evanxmerz.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/07/recording-in-game-audio-in-unity/